# How to remove parameters from url in laravel?

Tags: laravel, url, query-string

I am trying to remove the url parameters based on some conditions ,i can able to remove some of the parameters , i want to replace the some new value for the url, can you please give me some idea how to do this one

```
$request->query->remove('key');
$request->query->add(['admin'=>"true"]);
$request->request->remove('key');
$request->request->add(['admin'=>"true"]);
```

Comment: Does something not work? What is the actual output after updating?

Comment: after updating it will fetch admin users whose value is true

Comment: You showed your "_Expected output_", what is the _actual output_ /URL after you ran the code you posted?

Comment: @brombeer, i updated the question please take a look

Comment: That still isn't the actual URL you get after running your code. Your question is about how to replace query parameters. You have `http://localhost.com/users?limit=25&page=1&search=xyz`, you apply the code you posted, is something _not_ replaced? What does the request/url look like after that? (Might be I'm completely misunderstanding your question)

Comment: My question is just for replacing the query parameters globally from this `http://localhost.com/users?limit=25&page=1&search=xyz` to `http://localhost.com/users?limit=25&page=1&open=true`

Comment: And does the code you posted not do that? What does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost done in a correct way, simply change the order of the queries then it will be working fine.

```
$request->query->remove('key');
$request->request->remove('key');
```

Comment: Thanks @Sai Tarun, it's working fine